# Can't figure out why I cannot invalidate an input if it is not YYYY-MM-DD in python

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is get an input in the YYYY-MM-DD specific format and it will output the amount of minutes someone has lived since their birthdate. But the function "invalidate" only seems to create errors. Without it the code works as long as you input the correct format. I've tried some regex code but haven't been able to make it work either. Also, would it be easier to do this within a class?

```
import datetime
import inflect
import sys
import re

##class Date:
    ##def __init__(self, year, month, day):


def main():
    birth = input("Birthdate: ")
    ##birthdate = invalidate(birth)
    print(num_to_words(days_between(format_date(birth))) + " minutes")

##def invalidate(x):
    #if x != "%Y-%m-d":
        #sys.exit("Invalid")


def format_date(e):
    year, month, day = map(int, e.split('-'))
    date1 = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    return date1

def days_between(f):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    diff = today - f
    x = diff.days * 24 * 60
    return x

def num_to_words(x):
    p = inflect.engine()
    words = p.number_to_words(x)
    return words


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `invalidate` function to this:

```py
def invalidate(x):
    if re.match(r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$', x):
        if datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'):
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')
        else:
            print("Invalid date")
            sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid date")
        sys.exit()
```

I have modified my code which now has an additional valid date check after valid format check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check it with `strptime` to see if it actually matches the format, not the exact string:

```
import datetime

def invalidate(x):
    # You were missing the % on d
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(x, r'%Y-%m-%d')
    except ValueError:
        return False # Or change this to exit
    return True # You could return your datetime object here too
```

```
>>> invalidate('2022-06-05')
True
>>> invalidate('2022-6-05')
True
>>> invalidate('')
False
>>> invalidate('2022')
False
```

---

In your original function, you were checking the exact match of the string:

```
>>> invalidate('%Y-%m-d') # This was the only thing that would match
>>> invalidate('2022-6-5')
Invalid
```